# Bootstrap <li> isn't responding to css?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this section of html:

```
<ul id="checkout">
    <li>
        <p>$1.99 Basket</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <form>
            QTY: <input type="number" name="quantity" min="0">
        </form>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And it displays like so:

[image]

For some reason the "$1.99 Basket" is not inline with the quantity form.

My CSS for the section is like so:

```
#checkout {
    display: inline;
}
```

I simply want the Price and Quantity field on the same level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ek70o0fv/)

Get rid of your `<p>` tags and add your `li`s to your css

```
<style>
    #checkout li {
         display: inline;
    }
    #checkout form {
        display: inline;
    }
</style>


<ul id="checkout">
    <li>
        $1.99 Basket
    </li>
    <li>
        <form>
            QTY: <input type="number" name="quantity" min="0">
        </form>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code to pull elements left or right.

```
#checkout li:nth-child(1) {
 display:inline-block;
 float:left;
}

#checkout li:nth-child(2) {
 display:inline-block;
 float:right;
}
```

After this code don't forget the clear with below code.

```
#checkout {
 clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Assuming you want them horizontally aligned:

You are setting the `<ul>` to `display: inline;`, but you need to set your `<li>` elements to `display: inline-block;` so that they will appear on the same line. Just targeting the `<ul>` will not affect the children.

(The `<li>` element's default `display` property value is [`list-item`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).)

```
#checkout li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```